Analogue of (anti)commutation relation for anyons
In textbook quantum field theory, bosons obey something like
$$[b_\sigma(\vec{x}, t),b_{\sigma'}(\vec{y}, t)^\dagger]\propto \delta_{\sigma \sigma'}\delta(\vec{x} - \vec{y})$$
and fermions obey something like
$$\{f_\sigma(\vec{x},t),f_{\sigma'}(\vec{y},t)^\dagger\}\propto \delta_{\sigma \sigma'}\delta(\vec{x} - \vec{y}).$$
What sort of commutation relation do anyonic quantum fields obey?

https://www.nature.com/articles/s42005-023-01245-6.pdf maybe this could be of some help to you

are you familiar with parastatistics $[a,b]_q=ab+q,ba$? It reproduces bosons if $q=-1$ and fermions if $q=+1$, and it smoothly interpolates between them if you take $q\in[-1,1]$.
